# SharePoint 2016 Search Error - Display Error: The display template had an error

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, search-results, error

In my SharePoint 2016 On -premises site, search is not working and giving the following error:

[image]

In my analysis i've found that **Group_default.js** file is not loading while searching, however when i navigate to the _catalogs/masterpageDisplay Templates/ Search  folder, i do see the group_default.js file is available.

I'm unable to edit/overwrite the file, how to fix this issue.  Please help me.

version history :
[image]

Comment: Is it checked out or have a major version published? Any changes to the version history? Is the corresponding HTML file there?

Comment: yes, its the major published version and there is no version history, its not checked out. Also the corresponding html file is there only

Comment: i've added the screenshot of the version history of that file

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Site collection feature and check if the feature "Search Server Web Parts and Templates" is activated. Try to **Deactivate and Activate the feature.**

If it still not works, using IE F12 developer tools to check if some errors occurs.

A troubleshooting blog for your reference:

https://www.eliostruyf.com/things-to-check-when-something-went-wrong-with-your-display-template/

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at your Result Type Rules. If they are conflicting or associated with the incorrect Display Template that can cause problems as well.